# MySql trigger is not created and gives syntax error

Tags: mysql

I want to create a trigger that after insert print out a statement, here is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrig after insert on adventureworks.salesterritory
    for each row 
BEGIN
     select 'INSERT IS NOT ALLOWED. YOU NEED APPROVAL';      
END
```

But it keeps getting my syntax error that I need to put semicolon after  `select 'INSERT IS NOT ALLOWED. YOU NEED APPROVAL';` although it already has it. Any suggestion how this can be fixed?

Comment: Please post actual error message.

Comment: try putting a semicolon after the `END` statement

Comment: @LukaszSzozda 13:47:30 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4... Line 4 is where I have the create keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `;` inside the `CREATE TRIGGER`, but at the same time `;` is meaningful as SQL command delimiter.

The way this problem is usually workarounded is by changing the delimiter to something else, say `$$`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER myTrig after insert on adventureworks.salesterritory
    for each row 
BEGIN
     select 'INSERT IS NOT ALLOWED. YOU NEED APPROVAL';      
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then changing back to `;`

Comment: I did but now got this error Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger... @Havenard

Comment: @nina_dev Yes, that is another problem. Triggers can be used to modify the data from an INSERT or even replicate the data to other tables (it's great to connecting two different systems), but they are not supposed to return anything, you can't return rows when performing an `INSERT`.

Comment: @nina_dev You should simply revoke write rights on that table, it's the way of doing it.

Comment: The credit goes to @Havenard. But please remember to comments that he had after posting the solution.